# How to deselect all the tabs of TabLayout in Android because of option menu?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabs

I am developing an Android app. I am using TabLayout for tabs. But I am not using pager view for fragment on tab selected. Instead I am replacing fragment on event listener to a view. I want to deselect all the tabs when an item in option menu is selected. But I saw an identical question in Stack Overflow. The answer is cannot do this. Because a tab must be selected.

This is UI design of my app:

[image]

As you can see in above design, PODCASTS tab is selected by default. This is where the issue begins.

Here are the screenshot of my option menu and function

[image]

[image]

The problem is when I select the settings while I am on PODCASTS tab, settings fragment is replaced. But the PODCASTS tab is still selected. But when I click again on, podcasts list fragment is not replaced back. How can I solve that problem ?

This is how I am adding tabs to tab layout in MainActivity:

```
private void setupTabs() {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Podcasts"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Playlist"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Downloads"));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch (tab.getPosition()){
                    case 1:
                        setPlaylistFragment();
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setDownloadsFragment();
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                    default:
                        setPodcastListFragment(0, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "ALL_FRAGMENT");
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Out of Curiosity, Why not `ViewPager`  with `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

Comment: Because I also have navigation drawer

Comment: so what navigation drawer has to do with ViewPager and TabLayout they are independent. Killing behavior O.o

Comment: they both can implement in same screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I just need to override the onTabReselected as well. So my listener will be like this.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch (tab.getPosition()){
                    case 1:
                        setPlaylistFragment();
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setDownloadsFragment();
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                    default:
                        setPodcastListFragment(0, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "ALL_FRAGMENT");
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch (tab.getPosition()){
                    case 1:
                        setPlaylistFragment();
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setDownloadsFragment();
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                    default:
                        setPodcastListFragment(0, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "ALL_FRAGMENT");
                        commitFragment();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of the selected tab when setting button pressed
`tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
 .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#393939"));`
and set the selected tab to some other tab i.e `setSelected(1)`

Your flow will be like that.If you are on tab-1 and you click setting button then on button click you can change your selected tab and background of selected tab.Now when user select the first tab he can see that tab content

P.s : because of less reputation i didn't comment it on your question

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you use a boolean to hold the states, for example, if I don't want a view A to show, I will make it conditional by creating a boolean say boolean showA and set it to false, on page rendered, I will set it to true, on click of the option Item you said, I will set that boolean to false again which will means A wont show as it depends on the boolean. That should do it. Hope this help.

Comment: For example, A for drawer items and B for option items ? Then I will have two main content views and toggle it conditionally ?